# In SQL, is there a way to split up a column in SQL that is stored as a list?

Tags: sql, presto, apache-zeppelin

I currently have a table that has a column stored as lists for whatever reason. It looks as follows:

```
Symbol      Exchange             Price
AAPL        [NYSE, CHX, PHLX]    22.02 
AAPL        [BSE, MS4X]          23.11
```

Is there a way to break up the table using SQL so it expands the columns to something like this:

```
Symbol      Exchange       Price
AAPL        NYSE           22.02 
AAPL        CHX            22.02
AAPL        PHLX           22.02
AAPL        BSE            23.11
AAPL        MS4X           23.11
```

Basically the goal is the break up the exchange column so that it has its own individual entries as lists.

Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of `exchange`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is an array, you can use `unnest()`:

```
select t.symbol, u.exchange, t.price
from t cross join
     unnest(t.exchanges) u(exchange);
```